# Grails installation error: Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, 13.10, ppa, grails

I have tried installing Grails using the answer found at [Error Installing Grails - Unmet Dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268576/error-installing-grails-unmet-dependencies) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grails-ppa
```

The first command returns without errors:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails
 Grails is an advanced and innovative open source web application platform that
 ...
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~groovy-dev/+archive/ubuntu/grails
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpt59mo9/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpt59mo9/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 02A9EC29 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpt59mo9/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 02A9EC29: public key "Launchpad PPA for Groovy Developers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

But the update command fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/groovy-dev/grails/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea why the ppa update fails with a 404 error?

Comment: change your server mirror following this article: http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/configure then update again.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.10 is no longer supported because it reached its end of life.
You should upgrade to 14.04 or use 12.04, the currently supported LTS versions, to get the newest (security) upgrades.

You are getting the 404 error because the ppa is no longer maintained, most likely because the eol of 13.10.

Comment: Still the first 404 error is beacuse of the no longer supported Ubuntu version.